# How to add a maven project's modules to the dependency list?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a project A which has a bunch of modules defined under it.

```
<groupId>groupA</groupId>
<artifactId>ModuleA</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>SubModule1</module>
    <module>SubModule2</module>
    <module>SubModule3</module>
</modules>
```

Now, I have a project B which needs to define all the SubModules of ModuleA as dependencies. I tried the following, but that doesn't work

```
<groupId>groupB</groupId>
<artifactId>ModuleB</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependency>
    <groupId>groupA</groupId>
    <artifactId>ModuleA</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to add SubModule1, SubModule2 and SubModule3 as dependencies without having to add them explicitly?

I am using maven 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

What about parent pom? Make a A as a parent and say to B about that A is parent :)

```
<parent>
    <groupId>groupA</groupId>
    <artifactId>ModuleA</artifactId>
    <version>INSERTYOURVERSION</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: And you cant recreate your hiearchy? This parent, call it C, will be parent of A and A will be parent for B?

Comment: That would mean restructing the whole project just to add the dependencies automatically. In that case, my preference would be to add each dependency separately (for submodule1, submodule2 and submodule3)